# Detect and Extract download link Like Internet Download Manager

Tags: java, http, browser, download

I just was curious on how a downloading software like Internet Download Manager capture a download from a browser. For example if I visit any website and press download, IDM automatically captures the link and ask to download through it.

When i searched all I found, was that to use a packet sniffer, and identify the HTTP Packets being sent and received. Is there any way to identify if a HTTP Request is actually a download request? (Or they meant, search for GET Requests, and check if there are standard extensions such as pdf, mp3 etc , to identify it is a download request). But in this case, how is it possible to do programmatically  through Java?